# Unable to Save and Re-load Gmail Cookies with Selenium/Splinter

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, gmail, splinter

My goal is to log-in to Gmail, serialize the cookies, exit the browser, then open a new browser, load the saved cookies, and check my email without needing to enter my log-in details. Pretty straight-forward, and I've been able to do this with almost every website I've tried. However, Gmail forces me to sign in again, each time.

Here's my code:

```
from splinter import Browser
import selenium
import pickle

def export_cookies(browser, the_name):
    yummy = browser.cookies.all(verbose=True)
    location = 'cookies/' + the_name
    pickle_save(yummy, location)
    print(the_name, "saved", len(yummy))


def pickle_save(obj, location):
    file_name = location
    file_object = open(file_name, 'wb')
    pickle.dump(obj, file_object)
    file_object.close()


def pickle_load_account(cookie_file_name):
    try:
        return pickle.load(open(cookie_file_name, "rb"))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return 0


def browser_add_cookies(browser, cookies):
    if len(cookies) > 0:
        for cookie in cookies:
            browser.cookies.add({cookie['name']: cookie['value']})
        print("-----", len(cookies), " cookies added, reloading")
        browser.visit('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox')
    else:
        print("No cookies to load. Error.")


browser = Browser('firefox')
browser.visit('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox')
cookie_file = "cookies/name"
load_cookies = pickle_load_account(cookie_file)
browser_add_cookies(browser, load_cookies)
browser.visit('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox')
input("Save cookies?")
export_cookies(browser, "name")
```

This code assumes the cookies were already saved, but then re-saves them in the end, so a second run (if you sign in manually the first time).

My guess is that Gmail somehow uses a more advanced method of cookie recognition?

Comment: Any feedback on the answer I posted?

Answer (score 1):

You are replicating cookies on for one domain. You need to replicate for below domains as well

```
accounts.google.com
mail.google.com
```

And may be even more, see the screenshot below on fresh login

[image: Domains]

Comment: This does not provide a solution because you will then get `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidCookieDomainException: Message: Cookies may only be set for the current domain (accounts.google.com)` because navigating to `mail.google.com` will force redirect to `accounts.google.com`

Answer (score 0):

Example code for a browser wrapper to make set cookies easier:

```py
class SplinterBrowserWrapper:
    def __init__(self, splinter_browser):
        b = self.browser = splinter_browser
        b.visit('https://' + ROOT_DOMAIN)

    def add_cookies(self, cookies: dict):
        self.browser.cookies.add(cookies)
        for cookie in self.list_cookies():
            cookie['domain'] = ROOT_DOMAIN
            self.add_single_cookie_dict(cookie)
        self.browser.reload()

    def add_single_cookie_dict(self, single_cookie_dict):
        self.browser.driver.add_cookie(single_cookie_dict)

    def get_cookies(self):
        return self.browser.cookies.all()

    def list_cookies(self):
        return self.browser.driver.get_cookies()
```

routine:

1. visit `mail.google.com`
2. `mail.google.com` ask `accounts.google.com`: this guy login or not?
3. `accounts` answer: NO!
4. `mail`: OK, just another wandering guest...

guest is not happy, tries to set cookies via splinter:

1. visit `mail.google.com` and set cookies
2. cookies are set, but bound with sub-domain `mail.google.com` (run `browser.driver.get_cookies()` and check the returned list)
3. sub-domain `accounts.google.com` still no cookies
4. `mail` ask `accounts` the same question and get the same NO answer
5. emmm...

guest knows the trick now, guest tries again:

1. visit `accounts.google.com` and set cookies
2. visit `mail.google.com`
3. `mail` ask `accounts`, get answer YES
4. `mail` login
5. N~I~C~E~

---

another routine, another website called bilibili:

- visit `www.bilibili.com`
- `www` ask `account.bilibili.com`
- `account` has no logged in cookies, `account` redirect browser to `passport.bilibili.com`
- `passport` ask user for username & password
- `passport` get correct auth, set cookies, and redirect back to home page as login

splinter chanllege bilibili, round 1:

- visit `www.bilibili.com`, set cookies, reload page, not login
- visit `account.bilibili.com`, be redirected to `passport.bilibili.com`
- set cookies on `passport`
- but `passport` not want cookies, `passport` NEED username & password
- `passport` stay put, refuse to redirect to `account` or `www`
- `account` still no cookies
- visit `account` again, redirected to `passport` again, dead loop

splinter challenge round 2:

- visit `www.bilibili.com`, set cookies, cookies are bound with `www.bilibili.com`
- dig into underlying selenium driver, list all cookies with `browser.driver.get_cookies()`, every single cookie in this list is a dict, with keys `name`, `value`, `path`, `domain`, `secure`, `httpOnly`
- iterate this cookies list, for every cookie dict, change value of `domain` to the parent domain `bilibili.com`, with no sub-domain
- set these manipulated cookies back into selenium drive one by one, via `browser.driver.add_cookie`
- now `account` see these cookies bound with its parent domain `bilibili.com`
- `account` is obedient, `account` accpet these cookies, `account` now answer YES when anyone ask if user is login
- reload the page and user login